# How to ceil/floor the float value of datetime

Tags: sql, postgresql

#### For min case

If the `min(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP` is `2014-01-02 01:14:45.5` , I want to convert it to `2014-01-02 01:14:45`

#### For max case

If the `max(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP` is `2014-01-02 01:14:45.5` , I want to convert it to `2014-01-02 01:14:46`

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (1) generate_series ( min(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP, max(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP, '1 second'::interval) AS ticktime
    FROM cffexes
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just cast the result to a second-less `timestamp` like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1) generate_series ( 
    min(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP(0), 
    max(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP(0)+1, 
    '1 second'::interval) AS ticktime
FROM cffexes;
```

If you want floor/ceil of time other than seconds, use `date_trunc()`.

Of course this leave open the ever so slight hole that if `max(ticktime)` is EXACTLY an even second, you will generate one too many. So you could try this, but realize that floating point values are notoriously unfriendly to equality.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1) generate_series ( 
    min(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP(0), 
    max(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP(0) + (max(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP(0)=max(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP)::int,
    '1 second'::interval) AS ticktime
FROM cffexes;
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply add **date_trunc** on the  start of generate_series,

And it works for my

```
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (1) generate_series
      (
        date_trunc('second', min(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP),
        max(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP,
        '1 #{frequence}'::interval
      ) AS ticktime FROM #{market} WHERE product_type ='#{product_type}' AND contract_month = '#{contract_month}'::timestamp
```